# Public structs inheriting private struct C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, forward-declaration

I have a class that controls all IO to/from a device. When a thread makes an IO request it's added to a FIFO queue in case another IO request is being handled at the time. As soon as an IO request has been completed it's popped off the queue and the next IO request is handled.

Leaving out extraneous functions, member variables, and ctors/dtors, my class is laid out like so:

```
class IOInterface
{
  public:
    struct ReadRequest: public IORequest
    {
      ReadRequest(int a, int b)
        : IORequest(a, b) {}
    };

    struct WriteRequest: public IORequest
    {
      WriteRequest(int a, int b)
        : IORequest(a, b) {}
    };

    void makeIORequest(IORequest request);

  protected:
    void performIO(ReadRequest request);
    void performIO(WriteRequest request);
    std::queue<IORequest> m_ioQueue;

  private:
    struct IORequest
    {
      IORequest(int a, int b)
        : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}
      int m_a;
      int m_b;
    }
}
```

(This isn't an exact copy of my code, so I don't think it will compile as is)

The idea is to be able to have a thread that would check if queue had a request and then simply call:

```
performIO(m_ioQueue.front());
```

The problem is that at compile time the compiler has no idea what IORequest is when it gets to ReadRequest and WriteRequest. I can't just move the private section of the class to the top because then the overloaded performIO functions don't know what ReadRequest and WriteRequest are.

I want to keep IORequest private so it can never be instantiated down the road when this IOInterface class gets inherited.

Normally this could be solved with forward declaration, but how can I forward declare IORequest while still keeping it private?

Is forward declaration the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your class is not compiling is that the definition of the private `struct` is textually after the place where you inherit it. Move the private section to the top of the class, so it would compile:

```
class IOInterface {
  private:
    struct IORequest {
      IORequest(int a, int b)
        : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}
      int m_a;
      int m_b;
    };
  public:
    struct ReadRequest: public IORequest {
      ReadRequest(int a, int b)
        : IORequest(a, b) {}
    };

    struct WriteRequest: public IORequest {
      WriteRequest(int a, int b)
        : IORequest(a, b) {}
    };

    void makeIORequest(IORequest request);

  protected:
    void performIO(ReadRequest request);
    void performIO(WriteRequest request);
    std::queue<IORequest> m_ioQueue;
};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/XQQyqz)